# Annoying horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

I am trying to create a page to scroll table content only, ie, table header doesn't move with content.

It looks good, except it has an annoying horizontal scrollbar (in all modern browsers).

code is here

```css
div.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 97px;
    width:100%;
}
div.tableHeader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    height: 23px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width:100%;
}
div.tableBody {
    position: absolute;
    top: 128px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
table.fixedHeader {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
table.fixedHeader thead {
    height: 21px;
    background-color: #BFC2CC;
}
table.fixedHeader tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(1), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 250px;
}
table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(2), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100px;
}
table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(3), table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(4), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(3), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(4) {
    width: 60px;
}
table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(5), table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(6), table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(7), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(5), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(6), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(7) {
    width: 120px;
}
table.fixedHeader th:nth-child(8), table.fixedHeader td:nth-child(8) {
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="title">
         <h1> Demo how to set fixed table header</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="tableHeader">
        <table class="fixedHeader">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>head1</th>
                    <th>head2</th>
                    <th>head3</th>
                    <th>head4</th>
                    <th>head5</th>
                    <th>head6</th>
                    <th>head7</th>
                    <th>head8</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tableBody">
        <table class="fixedHeader">
            <tr>
                <td>Text 1111</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>3333</td>
                <td>4444</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 2222</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>3333</td>
                <td>4444</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 3333</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>3333</td>
                <td>4444</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 4444</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>3333</td>
                <td>4444</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 5555</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 6666</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 7777</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 8888</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text 9999</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text aaaa</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text aaaa</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text bbbb</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text cccc</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text dddd</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
                <td>Even More Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text eeee</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text ffff</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text gggg</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text hhhh</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text iiii</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
                <td>Text Text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a reset stylesheet or set the `body { margin: 0; }` to avoid having to hide any `overflow.`

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, if you decide not to use box-model, clear that specific margin, or use a reset stylesheet,  you'd have to set the overflow-x to hidden on either the parent of the table or the body.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the CSS overflow-x: hidden; to the table.

Comment: horizontal scrollbar didn't belong to the table.  I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, try adding "overflow-x: hidden;" for div.tableHeader.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need is to add `overflow-y: hidden;` to your  `.tableHeader` div

here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gcfurtqs/4/

Comment: I still saw that horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Hi , the horizontal scrollbar you are seeing belongs to <body> so i updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gcfurtqs/5/ , but it is NOT recommended not to put `overflow-x:hidden` for body , you're better off wrapping the entire table in a div and applying it to the wrapper

Comment: Charbz, it works on body,  Thanks! But it can't work on any div container